# VS Code Ruby debugger is not responding

Tags: ruby, debugging, visual-studio-code, environment

I've been trying to set up my Ruby environment in VS Code for quite some time, and I keep hitting a wall. Here is some information:

-Ruby version: 3.0.0 (as verified by ruby -v)

-VS Code Version: 1.52.1

-OS: Windows 10

-VS Extensions I have installed for Ruby: Ruby, VSCode Ruby, Ruby Solagraph, rubocop, Code Runner, endwise

I've also configured my PATH variable and am fairly certain it's correct.

When I try to use the debugger, nothing happens. There is an error in the debug console that says:
Debugger error: Client: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1234

In addition to that, the output of my code won't show up in the VS Code output window. I have to use a Windows Powershell window.

Here's my launch.json file:

```html
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for rdebug-ide",
            "type": "Ruby",
            "request": "attach",
            "remoteHost": "127.0.0.1",
            "remotePort": "1234",
            "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? I'm feeling a little hopeless about it.

Comment: The error is from solargraph engine not starting. You'll need to look into why it isn't working. I ended up using WSL2 for my ruby environment on Windows, as it was a significant less pain to get it working

Comment: Ruby 3 just came out, try 2.7.